# Jacobi Method in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I've tried to write a code of jacobi method . In every iteration ,I want a return of x (approached solution ) and x_e (exact solution) .But the function returns only x and if I do a print it returns NAN values , any help please ?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la

def jacobi (A,b,ep,x0,Imax):
   M=np.diag(np.diag(A))  
   E=(-1)*np.tril(A-M)
   F=(-1)*np.triu(A-M)
   N=E+F

   vp= np.linalg.eigvals(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(M),N))#eigenvalues
   rho=np.max(vp) #max value of eigenvalues

   iter=0
   x=x0
   while iter < Imax and np.max(abs(b-np.dot(A,x))) > ep  :
       iter=iter+1
    
       x=np.dot(np.linalg.inv(M),np.dot(N,x)+b) #approached solution
       x_e=np.linalg.solve(A,b) #exact solution
       err=la.norm(x_e-x) #error
   return[x,x_e,err,iter]

    
  
   ep,Imax,x0=0.000001,1000,np.zeros(4)     
   A = np.array([[10.,7.,8.,7.],[7.,5.,6.,5.],[8.,6.,10.,9.],[7.,5.,9.,10.]])
   b=np.array([32.,23.,33.,31.]) 

   l=[x,x_e,err,iter]=jacobi(A,b,ep,x0,Imax)
   print(l)
```

results :
return without print : (it returns only the 'x')

```
[-2.47579145  0.56219805  0.99845116  0.91514225]
```

when i print l ,(x become nan nan ...nan and err returns nan) :

```
[array([nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([1., 1., 1., 1.]), nan, 781]
```

Comment: Your test matrix is not diagonally dominant, the Jacobi method is thus very likely to diverge.